# Output the names of all files from file.txt, having the .conf extension

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to output from a file file.txt the names of all files with the .conf extension.

```
grep .conf file.txt
```

But in the end, I get a file called dconf and a file with the config extension. How can I output everything else, but without these two?

Comment: What does the input file look like? is it one filename per line? can you reasonably assume that the filename extension would be followed by EOLN?

Comment: I added what the file looks like.

Comment: You should not add pictures of text files and especially not as link! Please give simply some lines as an example. ( BTW: I understand how your file is structured without any example, because your description is quite perfect! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '.' has a special meaning, it says "any character". If you really want to match only the dot itself, you have to mask the character with:

```
grep "\.conf" file.txt
```

The masking with backslash must also be masked for the shell itself with `"`.

To see a list of regular expressions, you can take a look at [online regex test](https://regex101.com/).

Add on:
From the comments: How to see no file from the list which is named `xyz.config`

Answer: You have to tell grep that the regular expression ends at the end of the word with:

```
grep "\.conf\>" file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, i get it now. But there is still exist file with extenction .config.

Comment: I have no enought reputation, sry.

Comment: @nobody: No problem :-) You will get it some Q&As later :-)

Comment: This answer is not a completely correct solution, as the given regular expression will still match anything containing `.config`

Comment: If you want the line to end with `.conf`, add an anchor: `grep '\.conf$' file.txt`

Comment: @JamesS. Fixed it

Comment: @WilliamPursell: $ searches to end of line which may fail if there are additional whitespaces. `\>` fits better I believe :-)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** you should instead do:

```
grep "\.conf\>" file.txt
```

`grep` uses [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). The `.` character in a regex is a command which means "match any one character." So your command means "match any string which contains one character followed by `c` `o` `n` `f` in that order."
So, your regular expression will match what you are looking for, but it will also match strings that have things *after* your match (your `.config` example) as well as *anything* followed by "conf" (your `dconf` example)

So instead you want to tell grep that you are looking for a "string literal ." by escaping that character in your regular expression by preceding it with a backslash (`\`), and you want to describe what the end or your string input is like, which may be a newline or it may simply be a space.

Comment: Thank you also for the clear explanation. I suppose I can also use grep "\. conf\b"

Comment: that whitespace would be regarded as part of the expression, so you would not get the response you are looking for.